# Insert Tables in Marp

Tags: pandas, markdown, presentation, marp

I amm using Marp to produce presentations in pdf (markdown syntax).
For a presentation i have to insert tables from pandas dataframe.
The trick i use for now is to print "to_markdown" thanks to pandas and copy paste the result into my markdown code, but i have no possibility to change font size and choose where to put the table.
The Marp [documentation](https://marpit.marp.app/) is not so helpful for this type of issue.
How can i modify font size and table localisation in markdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can style the table in any way you'd like through the availability of the style attribute (both globally or scoped to just a single slide).

For example, you can take your markdown tables and chnage their appearance by adjusting the necessary CSS selectors. By default this will apply globally but if you add `scoped` after the `style` tag then it will only act on that slide. (See the [marp documentation](https://marpit.marp.app/theme-css?id=scoped-style) for more info).

This allows you to set-up all kinds of styles for tables -- even setting a general style that can be tweaked as necesasry for each slide.

See the example below.

```
---
marp: true
theme: default
---

<style scoped>
table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}
th {
    color: blue;
}
</style>

# Fruit Table -- styled

Fruit | Colour | Amount | Cost
-----|------|:-----:|------:
Banana | Yellow | 4 | £1.00
Apple | Red | 2 | £0.60
Orange | Orange | 10 | £2.50
Coconut | Brown | 1 | £1.50

---

# Fruit Table -- default

Fruit | Colour | Amount | Cost
-----|------|:-----:|------:
Banana | Yellow | 4 | £1.00
Apple | Red | 2 | £0.60
Orange | Orange | 10 | £2.50
Coconut | Brown | 1 | £1.50
```

Comment: Thank you for your documented answear! i wille test it asap. Nevertheless, in your answear you do not indicate how can i change the position of the table in the slide. I will have a look to the html commands to perform that. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: You can use something like this in the table css:

`position:fixed;
left:400px;
top: 500px;`. Just play around with the values to move it exactly where you want them.